# Exclude transitive dependency of Gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle

Excluding a transitive dependency in Gradle is pretty straightforward:

```
compile('com.example.m:m:1.0') {
     exclude group: 'org.unwanted', module: 'x'
  }
```

How would we go around he situation in which we use a plugin:

```
apply: "somePlugin"
```

And when getting the dependencies we realize that the plugin is bringing some transitive dependencies of its own?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can manipulate the classpath of the buildscript itself through:

```
buildscript {
    configurations {
        classpath {
            exclude group: 'org', module: 'foo' // For a global exclude
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('org:bar:1.0') {
            exclude group: 'org', module: 'baz' // For excluding baz from bar but not if brought elsewhere
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can remove dependencies after the plugin is applied, (from a single configuration, or to all configurations) using eg. `compile.exclude`. Note that `compile` resolves to a "Configuration"; see the javadocs at [Configuration.exclude](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.html#exclude-java.util.Map-) .

**edit**

Be aware that excluding dependecies could fail, if the configuration has already been *resolved*.

---

Sample script

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'ant:ant:1.6'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8'
}

// remove dependencies
configurations.all {
  exclude group:'junit', module:'junit'
}
configurations.compile {
  exclude group:'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-lang3'
}

println 'compile deps:\n' + configurations.compile.asPath
```

Answer (score 1):

Gradle >=5.x You can do the following way for either compileClasspath, runtimeClasspath, testCompileClasspath or testRuntimeClasspath. Depending on your use case.

```
configurations {
    testRuntimeClasspath {
        exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
    }
}
```

You can see how each hierarchy works fore more information https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#tab:configurations

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to enforce your project to strictly use a specific version for the build.gradle.kts

```
val grpcVersion = "1.45.1"

implementation("io.grpc:grpc-stub") {
 version {
     strictly(grpcVersion)
   }
}
```

More info can be found at the gradle documentation: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html